# Difference in ROC-AUC scores in sklearn RandomForestClassifier vs. auc methods

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, roc, auc

I am receiving different ROC-AUC scores from sklearn's RandomForestClassifier and roc_curve, auc methods, respectively.

The following code got me an ROC-AUC (i.e. gs.best_score_) of 0.878:

```
def train_model(mod = None, params = None, features = None, 
        outcome = ...outcomes array..., metric = 'roc_auc'):
    gs = GridSearchCV(mod, params, scoring=metric, loss_func=None, score_func=None, 
        fit_params=None, n_jobs=-1, iid=True, refit=True, cv=10, verbose=0, 
        pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', error_score='raise')
    gs.fit(...feature set df..., outcome)

    print gs.best_score_
    print gs.best_params_

    return gs

model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=2000, n_jobs=-1)
features_to_include = [...list of column names...]

parameters = {
            'n_estimators': [...list...], 'max_depth':[...list...],
            'min_samples_split':[...list...], 'min_samples_leaf':[...list...]
            }

gs = train_model(mod = model, params = parameters, features = features_to_include)
```

Whereas, the following code got me an ROC-AUC of 0.97:

```
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
fpr['micro'], tpr['micro'], _ = roc_curve(...outcomes array..., 
                                    gs.predict_proba(...feature set df...)[:, 1])
roc_auc['micro'] = auc(fpr['micro'], tpr['micro'])
```

Why is there such a difference? Did I do something wrong with my code?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would return different values, for two reasons:

1. since the `GridSearchCV` method splits your data into 10 groups (you are doing 10-fold cross-validation in your code), uses 9 for training, and reports the AUC on the last group. The best_score_ you get is just the highest-reported AUC reported as such (more info read [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV)). Your `roc_curve` calculation reports the AUC on the entire set.
2. The default cross-validation `roc_auc` is the macro version (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score)), but your later computation computes the micro version.

Comment: Great. So if I were to report AUC 'officially' for this model, I would use the second one (0.97)? And I'm guessing the 'micro' version is probably better than 'macro' in this case, because it takes label imbalance into account. That said, do you know of a good explanation of 'micro' vs. 'macro' (bonus if  it pertains to AUC calculations)?  My dataset has a bunch of True Falses and Prediction Falses that wouldn't show up in False Positive Rate or True Positive Rate. Would this affect my decision of using micro vs macro? Thanks!!

Comment: Not exactly - to report a reasonable AUC 'officially' you need some kind of held-out test set that wasn't trained on. Using training data to report testing / performance metrics is cheating, and always over-reports. I would use the LOWER (first) score as the AUC you report. For macro vs. micro, the link I posted should explain it.

Comment: Re: Average - "Will be ignored when y_true is binary."