# sklearn auc score - diff metrics.roc_auc_score & model_selection.cross_val_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc

Please be gentle, new to sklearn.  Calculating customer churn, using different roc_auc scoring I get 3 different scores. Scores 1&3 close, significant difference between those and score 2.  Grateful for guidance on why such a difference and which may be the preferred? Many thanks!

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


param_grid = {'n_estimators': range(10, 510, 100)}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(criterion='gini', max_features='auto',
                    random_state=20), param_grid=param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=4, iid=False, cv=5, verbose=0)
grid_search.fit(self.dataset_train, self.churn_train)
score_roc_auc = np.mean(cross_val_score(grid_search, self.dataset_test, self.churn_test, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc'))
"^^^ SCORE1 - 0.6395751751133528

pred = grid_search.predict(self.dataset_test)
score_roc_auc_2 = roc_auc_score(self.churn_test, pred)
"^^^ SCORE2 - 0.5063261397640454

print("grid best score ", grid_search.best_score_)
"^^^  SCORE3 - 0.6473102070034342
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is answered by the below linked, which points to the folding in GridSearchCV and scoring on smaller splits?

[Difference in ROC-AUC scores in sklearn RandomForestClassifier vs. auc methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818237/difference-in-roc-auc-scores-in-sklearn-randomforestclassifier-vs-auc-methods)